# Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED Manifest Merger Failed with multiple errors in React Native. My current Android Sdk Version 31

Tags: react-native

I was working fine on my react native project suddenly got this error. Didn't find any solution till now. Spent almost day finding the solution but couldn't find any solution. any kind of help will be appreciated.

my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.wiltreactnative">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
      
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding implementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0" to android/app/build.gradle dependencies [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iCqL.png)

Comment: Thanks. It worked but can u explain a bit about this?